# Where clause with table condition

Tags: sql

I would like to write a query which will `“filter”` the number of rows returned based on the status of a truck. From the UI I send a value of `‘1’` if I only wish to see trucks which have not been closed, a `‘2’` to see all trucks.

```
select *
from invoice left outer
join truck
     on (invoice.invnum = truck.invnum)
```

This returns the correct number of rows.

**Problem:**
I need a where clause that will look at the `close_date` field of the truck table and determine if it is null or not. Here is the catch, if there is no records found in the truck table, still return the row from the invoice table.

```
select *
from invoice left outer
join truck
     on (invoice.invnum = truck.invnum)
where UI.value = (select close_date from truck where invoice.invnum = truck.invnum) “if no record is returned here, return the value ‘2’
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the `where` clause a bit. Or at least what it can do for you here. Is it possible that you put this in a stored procedure wrapped in `if` statements?

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify your question.  Are you looking to do something like this?

```
select *
from 
    invoice 
     left outer join 
    truck on 
        invoice.invnum = truck.invnum
where 
    (UI.value = 1 AND truck.close_date IS NULL) OR
    (UI.value = 2)
```

Or are you looking to do this?

```
select *
from 
    invoice 
     left outer join 
    truck on 
        invoice.invnum = truck.invnum
where UI.Value = 
  (
    SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(close_date) IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END 
    FROM truck 
    WHERE invoice.invnum = truck.invnum)
```